# Create views in resource in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a beginner working with Rails: I have this `routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :requirements
  root "department#index"
  get "department/about"
end
```

How can I create a view that has a path like `requirements/major`?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend resources and add custom actions, like this:

```
 resources :requirements do
   collection do
     get :major
   end
 end
```

You'll need an action in the `RequirementsController` that matches, e.g.

```
class RequirementsController < ApplicationController

  def major
    # set up whatever resource 'major' corresponds to
  end

  ...
end
```

That's at least one way of doing it. You could also have a controller that directly supports the nested 'major' resource, which would be similar to above - just with a `controller: 'name of controller'` directive inline..

It'd probably pay to get your head around the "Rails Routing from the Outside In" guide: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Thank you for your help! It worked! I could only access it using `http://127.0.0.1:3000/requirements/major`. When I tried with `link_to` under `major_requirements`, it said `NameError in Requirements#index` `undefined local variable or method 'major_requirements'`. How can I fix this?

Comment: I'd need to see your code to figure out what's going on, but I suspect it's how you are using the path helpers. The link_to should looks something like `link_to 'major requirements', major_requirements_path`.